# How to enable TCP/IPV4 disabled on LAN via command prompt

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tcp, local-area-network, ipv4

I have unchecked tcp/ipv4 protocol from LAN properties & now iam unable to access the server or connect remotely.
However i have serial console access to the server where i can use netsh command.

Kindly advise as i am stuck since 3 days & also i cannot get my data stored @ the server.

Comment: it might help if you mention the operating system

Comment: OS: Windows 2008 R2 Web edition

Comment: You could try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770948 'set interface eth0 ENABLED'  - otherwise I think you may need to have someone onsite hook up a keyboard, mouse and monitor to re-enable that for you in person.

Comment: The question is actually interesting... I can't seem to find a way to enable/disable a *protocol* on a given interface via `netsh`, although this can easily done via GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Use IPv6 instead of IPv4. Done!

Failing that, you could try something like this. I suggest you check what each of these commands do before running them as I have not looked into your specific problem, this comes from crib notes of mine:

```
pushd interface
reset all
popd

pushd interface ip

# Interface IP Configuration for "eth0"
set address name="eth0" source=static addr=172.16.0.42 mask=255.240.0.0
set address name="eth0" gateway=172.16.0.1 gwmetric=0
set dns name="eth0" source=static addr=172.16.0.2 register=PRIMARY
set wins name="eth0" source=static addr=none

popd
```